# React-Native Image Not Showing

Tags: react-native, image

Okay, so I have a react-native screen looking like

```
const SentimentScreen = ({ navigation, route }) => {
    return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                 
                  <View style={styles.container}>
                    <Text style={styles.titleText}>Sentiment: {route.params.sent}</Text>
            <Image
                    style={{width: '100%', height: '50%'}}
            source={{uri:route.params.url}}
                />
                  </View>
              <StatusBar style="auto" />
            </View>

    );
};
```

And the url param is a string like 'https://www.example.com/lol.png'

But the image doesn't show. What am I doing wrong? (I'm still kind of a noob in terms of react-native)

Comment: It may not like the relative width/height.   maybe try specifying those explicitly, eg `{width:200,height:100}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take out the image from path first give it specific, height , width and size .Then you can pass in uri.